# textStorage and -ComponentsSepratedByString

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.I'm a newer in Object-C. Now, I want to create a small application which can tell me how many words in the text field.
I create an Empty NIB in Interface Builder, when I click "Show Info" menu, a panel will tell me how many words I have inputted.

In .h file:

> Blockquote

```
IBoutlet NSTextView *textView;
IBOutlet NSTextField *textLengthField;
IBOutlet NSTextField *wordCountField;
```

> Blockquote

In .m file:

> Blockquote

```
-(IBAction)showInfoPanel:(id)sender
{
    ...
    [textLengthField setIntValue:[[textView textStorage] length]];                     //a
    [wordCountField setIntValue:[[**textStorage** componentsSepratedByString:@" "]count]]; //b
   ...
}
```

> Blockquote

When I compile, Xcode tell me wrong. "In sentence b, **textStorage undeclared**".Then I try: 
NSTextStorage *storage = [textView textStorage]; but Xcode tell me "NSTextStorage may not respond to -componentsSepratedByString:".

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've left out an `a`: the method is named `componentsSeparatedByString:`.